# Is there a way to run a BigQuery stored procedure from Google Data Studio, with parameters?

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am trying to setup a Google Data Studio report for data that only needs to be accessed intermittently, such that refreshing the data on an interval in a table would be more expensive than just refreshing it as needed. For this reason, I have written a procedure in BigQuery that SELECTs the required data (given a number of parameters), with the intent to call the procedure on an as needed basis from Data Studio.

I thought it must be possible to add a BigQuery connector and create a custom query with the contents e.g.

```sql
CALL `my-project`.MyDataset.myProcedure(@myparameter);
```

And parameters defined for the custom query, such as:

[image]

But, when I save the custom query I am getting an error such as:

[image]

However, if I do not use a parameterized value, I am able to save the custom query. Such as:

```sql
CALL `my-project`.MyDataset.myProcedure("myvalue");
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to save a custom query, with a called procedure, with parameters?